# Compiler complains about class that extends DelayedInit not defining delayedInit method

Tags: scala

I have a class that I'm trying to make extend `DelayedInit`:

```
class Foo extends DelayedInit {
  // expensive initialisation code
}
```

However when I try to run `sbt compile` I get the error:

```
Foo needs to be abstract, since method delayedInit in trait DelayedInit of type (x: => Unit)Unit is not defined
```

My understanding is that by extending the `DelayedInit` trait any initialisation code should automatically be wrapped in a closure and run in the `delayedInit` method after initialisation is complete. However I've had a stab at googling and can't seem to find an example of usage. What am I missing?

Comment: implement delayedInit method and you're golden. The compiler is telling you to do just this.

Comment: My understanding was that you didn't need to? I thought the whole point of the trait was that the compiler did that for you - meaning you didn't need to declare your immutable variables as `var`s for example.

Comment: What you do not need to do is call delayedInit in your code.  You do, however, need to provide a concrete implementation to be called.  def delayedInit(x: => Unit) { initialisation code... } should do the trick

Comment: You were nearly right - you need to implement it but it's not for initialisation code - you just need to call the passed closure which is automatically generated from the initialisation code. Why the trait doesn't include a default implementation is beyond me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### How `DelayedInit` Works and its Sample Usage

`DelayedInit` trait provides the ability to control at which point initialisation code within a class or an object (but not a trait) is run.

Any initialisation code within classes or objects (but not traits) that are inherited from `DelayedInit` is passed by compiler during the initialisation to the `delayedInit` method and then it's up to you when you want to run it.

`delayedInit` method is called automatically as part of the initialisation and running the code that is passed as a parameter straight away within the method is still running the code during the initialisation.

Let's start with a basic scenario:

```
object Main extends DelayedInit  {

   println ("  initialisation of Main object")
   override def delayedInit (body: => Unit) {
     println("delayedInit")
     body
   }

   def main (args: Array[String]) {
     println("main method") 
   }
}
```

Will print:

> ```
> delayedInit
>   initialisation of Main object
> main method
> ```

In fact, `delayedInit` method will be called once for every class that inherits the trait within the class hierarchy. A slightly more complicated scenario:

```
abstract class MyApplication extends DelayedInit {
   println ("  initialisation of MyApplication class")
}

object Main extends MyApplication  {

   println ("  initialisation of Main object")
   override def delayedInit (body: => Unit) {
     println("delayedInit")
     body
   }

   def main (args: Array[String]) {
     println("main method") 
   }
}
```

Will print:

> ```
> delayedInit
>   initialisation of MyApplication class
> delayedInit
>   initialisation of Main object
> main method
> ```

Since `main` method is the first method to run once the initialisation is over, what we really want to do is to save all the initialisation code passed to `delayedInit` and run it later, probably from within `main`, since there is potentially more than one bit of code we could conveniently store it in a `ListBuffer` (we need to keep appending to preserve the natural execution order). The code inside 'Main` object could look something like this:

```
private val init = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[()=>Unit]
override def delayedInit (body: => Unit) {
  println("delayedInit")
  init += (()=>body) // will result in NullPointerException
}


def main (args: Array[String]) {
  println("main method") 
  for (code <- init) code ()
}
```

However, there is a catch 22: because initialisation of `init` field is delayed along with every other initialisation statement there isn't any `ListBuffer[()=>Unit]` object to preserve the initialisation code for later use!

But, remember?

> Any initialisation code within classes or objects **(but not traits)**
>   that are inherited from `DelayedInit` is passed by compiler during the
>   initialisation to the `delayedInit` method...

Let's re-shuffle things a bit, move functionality that memorises the code for later use into `StoredInit` trait that inherits directly from `DelayedInit`:

```
trait StoredInit extends DelayedInit {
   println ("initialisation of StoredInit trait")
   private val init = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[()=>Unit]
   override def delayedInit (body: => Unit) {
     println("delayedInit")
     init += (()=>body)
   }   
   def initialise () {
     for (code <- init) code ()     
   }
}

// extend StoredInit instead of DelayedInit
abstract class MyApplication extends StoredInit {
   println ("  initialisation of MyApplication class")
}

object Main extends MyApplication  {

   println ("  initialisation of Main object")

   def main (args: Array[String]) {
     println("main method") 
     initialise() // finally perform the delayed initialisation
   }
}
```

Will print:

> ```
> initialisation of StoredInit trait
> delayedInit
> delayedInit
> main method
>   initialisation of MyApplication class
>   initialisation of Main object
> ```

**Finally, why doesn't `DelayedInit` trait include a default implementation of `delayedInit` method?**

To keep the compiler hook de-coupled from the actual implementation of delayed initialisation behaviour. The desired behaviour will be different for console application and server-side component that has to work within a specific container.

[`trait App`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/App.scala#L1), however, inherits from `DelayedInit` and provides default implementation for Scala applications.

Comment: @Russell I quite enjoyed writing up what I know about `DelayedInit`.

Answer (score 0):

@virtualeyes, in a comment, was nearly right. You do need to override `delayedInit`, but you *don't* put the initialisation code in it.

`delayedInit` is passed the initialisation code from the primary constructor as a closure, so all it has to do is call that closure (if you want the initialisation to happen straight after the class is constructed).

As far as I can see it's there so that traits like `App` can get hold of the initialisation code and store it for execution at a different time. In the case of `App`, that's when the `main` method is called.

Why `DelayedInit` doesn't provide a default implementation that just runs the closure is beyond me, but perhaps someone can explain?

Anyway, to illustrate what I mean here's a REPL session:

```
scala> class A extends DelayedInit {
     | val x = 5
     | println("cats"*x)
     | def delayedInit(x: => Unit) = x
     | }
defined class A

scala> val a = new A
catscatscatscatscats
a: A = A@6192094b

scala> class B extends DelayedInit {
     | val x = 5
     | println("cats"*x) //should still be printed if this is constructor code
     | def delayedInit(x: => Unit) = println("dogs"*5)
     | }
defined class B

scala> val b = new B
dogsdogsdogsdogsdogs
b: B = B@7bff6a5f
```

And as an interesting aside, I've just noticed that if you don't call the closure in `delayedInit` the `val`s that you define in the initialisation code still exist, but default to, well, default values. Is this reassignment of `val`s??!

```
scala> b.x
res5: Int = 0

scala> class C extends DelayedInit {
     | val x = "hello"
     | println(x)
     | def delayedInit(x: => Unit) = println("dogs"*5)
     | }
defined class C

scala> val c = new C
dogsdogsdogsdogsdogs
c: C = C@35f4a968

scala> c.x
res6: java.lang.String = null
```